# How to automatically execute a js event (non-click event) when dotNetCore Blazor loads an index.razor page

Tags: asp.net, blazor

**Excuse me, everyone, how to enter Index.razor to automatically execute a js event**

The carousel plugin used needs to automatically execute the following code

```
function(){
    $("#banner").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay : 3000,
        paginationSpeed : 1000,
        goToFirstSpeed : 2000,
        singleItem : true,
        autoHeight : true,
        navigation: true,
        transitionStyle: 'fade'
    });
}
```

Such ineffective no longer should need to load the event in the child page
[_Host.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD1vF.png)

出现一个错误
[Index.razor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPYrh.png)

[出现Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw13B.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use `document.ready` ?

Comment: That's not incompatible

Comment: put your function at the end of _Host.cshtml in script tag

Comment: Written in the _Host.cshtml page is useless and should be called at Index

Comment: Ok, I get it. it doesn't exist at boot time. see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a JS interop function like that :

**wwwroot/scripts/interop.js**

```js
window.carousel = {
   play: (id, options) => {
     $(id).owlCarousel(options);
   } 
}:
```

Launch it when your carousel at id is ready in your razor page or component.

**Index.razor**

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<div id="banner"></div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
       if (!firstRender)
       {
           return;
       }
       await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("carousel.play", "#banner", new
       {
            autoPlay = 3000,
            paginationSpeed = 1000,
            goToFirstSpeed = 2000,
            singleItem = true,
            autoHeight = true,
            navigation = true,
            transitionStyle = "fade"
       });
    }
}
```

And launch your script in the _Host.cshtml

```html
    <script src="scripts/interop.js"></script>
```

Comment: In this:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You need to take those properties as parameters

Comment: It should be fine if those properties can be written in a js script

Comment: You  can choose what is the best for you, it's just a sample. You can put it in the js if you want.

Comment: Object reference is not set to an instance of an Object

Comment: That don't tell me which one, and if it is in your code

Comment: Ok, it because you use server-side : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13396, put the code on afterrender

Comment: The third picture of the problem above

Comment: Error：Whether "__generation__Index.OnAfterRenderAsync (bool)" is an asynchronous method that returns "Task", so the return keyword cannot be followed by an object expression. Do you want to return "Task <T>"?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem has been solved

Comment: AutoPlay = 3000,
            PaginationSpeed = 1000,
            GoToFirstSpeed = 2000,
            SingleItem = true,
            AutoHeight = true,
            Navigation = true,
            TransitionStyle = "fade"     
I'm still going to write this in js, otherwise it won't work. Can I change the code

Comment: Why it doesn't work ? Is it because values are not well serialized ?

Comment: The image can be displayed, but the properties don't work

Comment: I changed the property to js and it has been implemented successfully. Thank you very much